# On the flow generated Symbols in QGIS (2.14), Function

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, symbology, icon

I'd like to use on the flow generated / assembled symbols in QGIS 2.14, but am not able to code with Python at all  (will later learn it).

Could someone give me a code-snippet with short comments on how to start an external program/perl/script incl catching the the return value (in this case the path to a new created icon).

Guess something alike should be possibel via
 -> Symbols -> SVG -> Data-Defined -> Function

Just to explain my idea..... I started leaning Perl (to handle CSV and JSON) to use it for WeatherUnderground-API calls for my current GIS project, to document and evaluate my recent Experimental Archeological project Living Mesolithic 2.0 (see also e2e.stoneage-network.com).
Due to svg is also only XML, it shouldnt be that difficult to 'assemble' new symbols (icons) which provide more information.

Comment: What do you mean by "flow generated symbols"? Please clarify what you are looking for. If possible, provide an example image.

Comment: I'm not asking for code on the symbol generation, only the code to execute an external program with some args.

Comment: By external program, do you want to open up QGIS externally and load or reference symbols?

Comment: I want to call an external program from "inside" QGIS.
This (so my suggestion) should be called by the "function option" at
Layer->Symbols->SVG->Data-Defined->Function

In fact it shoulkd be possible to solve the proble by 'function' itself, but I'm not able to program in Python, so I have to spawn to an external program (perl?) to do the job.